# Is it possible to remove the circular referance from this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, circular-reference

I currently have a piece of code which contains a circular referance that I would like to remove. What it will do, which has not been implemented, is retrieve a "lock" from an API, this lock may be unlocked or active and the only way to truely know if by calling this API. This request to the API will occur with in the `taskWhichMayRequireRemoval` function.

```
class ExtensionManager{
    constructor(){
        this.locks = []; //Referance
    }

    remove(lock){
        this.locks.filter(lock => lock != lock)
    }

    add(lock){
        this.locks.push(lock);
    }
}

class RandomEventManager extends ExtensionManager{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}


 class RandomEventLock{
    
    constructor(manager){
        this.manager = manager; //Circular

    }

    taskWhichMayRequireRemoval(){
        //Example

    }
}
```

Ive tried many different solutions to tackle this problem, however, this is the only solution that has actually worked in a costly manor. The reason why im reluctnant to try this solution is becuase ive never used a circular dependancy in production before and I know they can cause issues with memory leaks. This is further reinforced as the host im using is very strict on how much memory I can use before I incur fees.

I have thought about constantly checking if a lock has been marked as removed every couple of seconds and then removing it if necessary however, this also seems like a waste of resources. I feel like there is a solution to this, I just cant work it out by myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does the lock need to know about the manager at all?  The lock should just do locking, and the manager should manage the lock.

Comment: @TimRoberts the example doesn't explain it very well. The random event lock will use a setInterval which triggers a random effect on that specific lock with that locks specific settings. I need to be able to enable and disable this when requested by the user. There will later be further lock with unique effects that may require similar functionality or something completely different, potentially interacting with other locks in the manger

Comment: Pass the `manager` to `taskWhichMayRequireRemoval`, not to the constructor? But it's really unclear how you plan to use these methods, how the instances are getting constructed, or why you think the circular reference is a bad thing.

Comment: For each extension, random events being one of them, there will be an ExtensionManager for that extension which will manage all the correlating locks. Theses managers will be declared at the start of the application. If a lock is required to stay, say for a random event to trigger in 2 hours, the lock will be stored in `this.locks` and removed when it is no longer needed. The reason why I don't want to use a circular reference is because quite a few sources from stack and other sites mention they can be bad. I also lack experience using them correctly.